# Strange behavior with horizontal scrolling UITableView (in Monotouch)

Tags: ipad, uitableview, xamarin.ios, horizontal-scrolling

We have a UITableView that we have configured to act like a Grid, allowing both horizontal and vertical scrolling. We accomplish this by dynamically changing the ContentSize in a custom UITableView's LayoutSubviews method, which helps with autorotation, scrolling, etc.

Everything works as expected except on a couple of our larger grids. When these grids are scrolled horizontally (swipe left), as soon as the ContentOffset.X is greater than or equal to the Bounds.Width, the table view disappears. It is still present and receives input, but nothing is painted. On swiping back to the right, as soon as the width threshold is crossed, everything is repainted.

In situations where the size of the grid is less than half of the configured UITableView width, this issue does not occur. We cannot change the size of the grids because they are configured by customers in the field who expect the data to be available.

I have checked and/or removed as much of our custom drawing code as possible and the issue is still occurring. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What's the advantage of abusing UITableView compared to a UIScrollView and implement a real multi-column solution for your needs?

Comment: The advantage of using UITableView is primarily cell re-use. Our users could have thousands of records in a given list with 5-20 columns. If we implemented scroll views, we'd have to resize the table views to their full size in order for the scroll view to scroll correctly and would thus have to create every single cell.

Comment: If I think back to games programming I did back in the late 90s, on every bit we scrolled to the bottom, we created the next screens rows on the hidden top. If one screen height was scrolled, the scorlling offset was reset and the next screen was already populated. This also works when scrolling up and down. I think the same technique would apply here. But it is indeed more work than using UITableView.

Answer (score 0):

That is because although the UITableView inherits from the UIScrollView, it is only meant to have a single column, hence it draws its cells according to its Bounds.

If you want to create a grid-like control with the UITableView, I suggest using multiple table views in a parent UIScrollView side-byside and change that one's ContentSize.

Comment: Because UITableView inherits from UIScrollView, adding SubViews to the UITableView and then setting the UITableView's ContentSize provides exactly the same solution as you have suggested with the added benefit of native UITableView cell re-use which is critical in large lists.

Comment: What sort of subviews do you want to add to a UITableView? Other table views?

Comment: Since we are emulating a grid, each subview is logically a column of data and programatically a UILabel.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this same issue and posted a bug report (**10561166**) back in December on the Apple Developer site.

I received a response today from Apple in which they stated that

> UITableView is not designed or intended for horizontal scrolling.

(I had since changed my design not to require the horizontal scrolling.)